# Ansible lineinfile is not changing file as expect

Tags: ansible

THi, new to this. . . .
Testing out a  Ansible play to update the swappiness setting on a test box.

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: swapness
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/sysctl.conf
      state: present
      regexp: vm.swappiness=*
      line: vm.swappiness=6
```

Currently, it is set to `vm.swappiness=4` but running the above does not change that.

the way I read the logic is...

look for a line with `"vm.swappiness="` and replace it with `"vm.swappiness=6"`

Answer (score 3):

I would do in this way:

```yaml
---
- name: Playbook who modify swapiness.
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: yes

  tasks:

    # Set vm.swappiness to 6 in /etc/sysctl.conf
    - name: Set swapiness.
      sysctl:
        name: vm.swappiness
        value: '6'
        state: present
        sysctl_set: yes
        reload: yes
```

The reason for that is that If exists any module for it, you should be doing using that module specific instead a generic one.

Ansible has a [sysctl](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/sysctl_module.html) module, so it's better to use it for this.

Note: Please, review the code and set 2 white spaces between them if not already.

Comment: This is much better! A bit off googling and I found a good example also. This one will reload the file for me also. I was using a new tash and the command module to do that part :) 



---
- name: Playbook who modify swapiness.
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: yes
  vars:
    sysctl_name: "vm.swappiness"
    sysctl_value: "5"
  tasks:
    - name: set sysctl
      ansible.posix.sysctl:
        name: "{{ sysctl_name }}"
        value: "{{ sysctl_value }}"
        state: present
        sysctl_set: true
        reload: true

Answer (score 0):

Given the file

```
shell> cat sysctl.conf 
vm.swappiness=4
```

The task below works as expected

```yaml
  - lineinfile:
      path: sysctl.conf
      regexp: vm.swappiness=*
      line: vm.swappiness=6
```

Running the playbook with the options `--check --diff` gives abridged

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] *****************************************************
--- before: sysctl.conf (content)
+++ after: sysctl.conf (content)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-vm.swappiness=4
+vm.swappiness=6
```

---

**Notes**

- The regexp `vm.swappiness=*` is probably not what you really want. This regexp matches the string `vm.swappiness` followed by 0 or mode `=`. For example, below are strings that match this regexp

```
vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness=
vm.swappiness==========
```

Instead, you want a regexp that matches the string `vm.swappiness=` followed by 0 or more characters. For example `vm.swappiness=.*`

Comment: You are correct on the .*( - thanks 
Your changes also worked but I wonder why you removed the state: present option.

Comment: Because it's [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-state). You're welcome.

Comment: @VladimirBotka It's best practice to always set the state especially when it's present, helps to clarify and understand it better.

Comment: @malpanez, in your opinion, what's the purpose of the default values?

Comment: @VladimirBotka In my opinion is to set a default value when no one is set. For that reason, it' s like in Python "explicit is better than implicit". It's okay to leave defaults but not necessarily you know or remember which ones are unless check on documentation. On top of that on [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#always-mention-the-state) says that the state might differ from module to module.

Comment: @malpanez, also "simple is better than complex". "lineinfile" says clearly it is "line in file".  The [best practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#always-mention-the-state) is questionable. I'm not aware of a module where the default is `state=absent`. Do you? I prefer common sense, or [tools not policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) to move forward.